# React Native Container Styling

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet, itemcontainerstyle

This is the container that I create looks:

---

[image]

---

This is the style I want.

---

[image]

---

How can I do this. The code is:

```
<View>
      {
        usersInfo.map((item) =>
        <View key={item.id} style={{}}>
        {Object.entries(item.intrest).map(([interestName, interestValue]) => (
        <View key={interestName} style={{ backgroundColor: interestValue === 'Games Online' ? '#6B7AED' : interestValue === 'Music' ? '#EE544A' : interestValue === 'Concert' ? '#FF8D5D' : interestValue === 'Movie' ? '#29D697' : '#6B7AED', borderRadius: 18,}}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: '500', paddingHorizontal: 15,paddingVertical: 7 }}>{interestValue}</Text>
        </View>
        ))}
        </View>
        )
        }
</View>
```

I want to style my containers like the sample given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to styling the `View` parent like this:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%'}}>
   {usersInfo.map((item) => (
      ....
   )}
</View>
```

Comment: its work but by putting this style  "style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%'}}" on 2nd view. after "usersInfo.map((item) => "

Comment: @MSTintern2 Cause you don't give value of `usersInfo`. You should provide enough information to ask

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to align the items by proper spacing:

```
 `<View>
      {usersInfo.map((item) => (
        <View key={item.id} style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}>
          {Object.entries(item.interests).map(([interestName, interestValue]) => (
            <View
              key={interestName}
              style={{
                backgroundColor:
                  interestValue === 'Games Online'
                    ? '#6B7AED'
                    : interestValue === 'Music'
                    ? '#EE544A'
                    : interestValue === 'Concert'
                    ? '#FF8D5D'
                    : interestValue === 'Movie'
                    ? '#29D697'
                    : '#6B7AED',
                borderRadius: 18,
                marginVertical: 5,
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: '#FFF',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: '500',
                  paddingHorizontal: 15,
                  paddingVertical: 7,
                }}
              >
                {interestValue}
              </Text>
            </View>
`
```

Comment: yes, I did it..

Comment: Does this one helped you out?

Comment: no, you only add marginVertical: 5, its not make it in the form that i want.